# Mensagem de erro (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest')

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Quando tento emular o aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo aparece o seguinte erro.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 3 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library /home/any/AndroidStudioProjects/CaronasFepi/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/7.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all" to force usage

Nunca apareceu esta mensagem antes, não sei como resolver.

Comment: Tente entrar no seu `Manifest` do seu app e no `minSdkVersion `, mude de 3 e coloque 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu  **`build.gradle(Module:app)`** altere o valor `minSdkVersion` para 9 e veja se resolve.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teste.net.appteste"
        minSdkVersion 9 // alterar aqui!!!!!
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: Deu certo ou não ?

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece quando você está utilizando alguma biblioteca que, em seu manifesto, exige uma versão mínima específica para o seu funcionamento.

No seu caso, o `Google Play Services` exige uma versão mínima a partir do **Android 2.3+ (Gingerbread, API 9)**

Para resolver isso, você simplesmente precisa alterar seu `minSdkVersion` para 9 (ou superior), dentro do seu `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Referência: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada!